# Log4j, dynamic file name based on .getLogger("") parameter

Tags: log4j

My application controls an arbitrary number of devices. I want to have log files for each of the devices. Basically, i want to be able to call `LogManager.getLogger(deviceId)` and log the corresponding thing.

I looked through a number of topics here and on other sites, still i am not quite sure if it is possible or not. I am not quite sure whether i should extend an appender or a logger.

How does one go about solving this task?

Answer (score 1):

One solution, though it's not optimal, would be to add a fileappender in the constructor of your device object :

```
String device = "thing"
Logger log1 = Logger.getLogger("org.path."+device);
log1.setAdditivity(false);
log1.addAppender(new FileAppender(new SimpleLayout(), "org.path."+device ));
```

Comment: The problem is that there is (currently) no "device" object. There is a number of processes that take device id as an argument (such as, there is an object that sends some data to a device, and it takes a device ID as a parameter. That is, we would have to add the new appender in multiple classes. The idea of doing that from a device object is good, and it needs considering.